# How to get VSCode Debugger to find electron source-maps

Tags: webpack, electron, vscode-debugger

I’m trying to set up VScode to debug an electron app, but when I try to start debugging my breakpoints all become unverified.

I’m pretty sure this is a source map issue, both from research I’ve done, and also all the logs reference the line numbers in the bundled code.

The version of electron is 2.0.0 and the version of webpack in use is 4.8.2.

There’s actually about nine different webpack.config.js files, for the environments and also so it can be built out as either an electron app, or as a standard web app for chrome. That being said I think this is the relevant webpack file that is bundling the code into various libraries:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const baseConfig = (root, src, options, entry, name) => {
    return {
        entry: entry,
        output: {
            filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
            path: `${root}${options.output.path}/libs`,
            library: name,
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            chunkFilename: '[name]-bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                _: 'lodash'
            }),    
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(options.defines)
        ],
        target: options.platform.lib,
        context: src,
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                src,
                'node_modules'
            ],
            alias: {
                app: 'app',
                util: 'app/util',
                robot: 'app/robot',
                platform: 'platform/' + options.platform.name
            },
            extensions: ['.json', '.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.mp4$|\.woff2?$|\.otf$|\.ttf$|\.eot$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
};

module.exports = (root, src, options) => {
    const configs = [];

    const libraries = [
        {
            entry: {messagingservice: 'util/messaging/messaging-service.js'},
            name: 'MessagingService'
        },
        {
            entry: {messagingclient: 'util/messaging/messaging-client.js'},
            name: 'MessagingClient'
        },
        {
            entry: {utils: 'util/utils-helper.js'},
            name: 'Utils'
        }
    ];

    libraries.forEach(library => {
        const config = baseConfig(root, src, options, library.entry, library.name);
        if (options.sourceMap) {
            config.devtool = 'source-map';
        }
        configs.push(config);
    });

    return configs;
};
```

And here is the configuration for the dev environment:

```
module.exports = {
    defines: {
        VERBOSE: true,
        SHOW_DEV_TOOLS: true,
    },
    output: {
        path: 'dev'
    },
    clean: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    mode: 'development',
};
```

Finally here’s the launch.json file in vscode:

```
   {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/electron/dev",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/electron/dev/index.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--enable-logging",
                "--remote-debugging-port=9223"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/electron/dev/**"
            ]
        },
```

What I’m really struggling with is figuring out if I should be spending my time in the webpack files (they do create source maps) of if this all has to do with getting the launch.json to find the source maps correctly.

VScode does offer this template:

```
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/*",
                "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*"
            }
```

But I’m a little unclear about what paths I’m trying to match up on the left and right sides. I think this template is out of date, and workspaceRoot should now be workspaceFolder, however I’m not sure why this template has me giving the path to the node modules folder, or if I need to make sure that these are equivalent to the paths I'm providing in the outFiles.

Also the files I care about debugging the most live in this folder `${workspaceFolder}/build/electron/dev/libs/` but I can't get the breakpoints to happen in files in the dev folder either.

Any insight on to where I should be focusing my efforts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured it out. It seems I made a few wrong assumptions along the way.

First off, clicking in VSCode to add a break point doesn't seem to work at all. It does work however if you type in `debugger` the same way you would in other java script code.

I had probably tried that at certain points, but I had thought the specific piece of code I was trying to debug was part of the Main processes. It wasn't, it was part of the Renderer, but that actually wasn't working.

These were the settings I had in my launch.json for the Renderer:

```
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9223,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/build/electron/dev",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "timeout": 3000,
        }
```

And whenever I tried to use this configuration I would get this error: 
`Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9223`
I found a lot on this error, but it was all related to "launch" requests not "attach" requests, so those solutions didn't work for me.

Finally I found this [vscode recipies](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron) specifically this section to add as a new configuration to my launch.json file:

```
"compounds": [
          {
              "name": "Electron: All",
              "configurations": [
                  "Electron: Main",
                  "Electron: Renderer"
              ]
          }
      ]
```

Running this configuration I can debug either the Main or the Renderer process and run them both simultaneously so that I don't have to worry about which process I'm trying to debug (and the debugger will tell me which one it is when I hit the break point).

Hope this helps someone else.